# Does surveyJS allow you to control when a survey participant receives a survey using their time zone?

Tags: surveyjs

I am evaluating the use of surveyJS in a ReactJS app. I want to ensure that surveyJS can be configured so that surveys can be sent to end users at a particular time in THEIR time zone before purchasing.

I can't seem to find any reference to that anywhere on their site.

Thank you.

I've been through their webiste.